# Nativescript Google Maps - Change polyline color

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, nativescript

In my Nativescript app I want to change Google Maps polyline color, docs say the following:

> Line segment color in ARGB format, the same format used by Color. The
>   default value is black (0xff000000).

I want to use this color

```
rgb(138, 191, 95)
```

I tried and failed with this:

```
drawRoute(encodedPolylinePoints) {
            this.mapView.removeAllPolylines();
            this.routeCordinates = decodePolyline(encodedPolylinePoints);
            this.polyline = new Polyline();
            this.routeCordinates.forEach(point =>
                this.polyline.addPoint(Position.positionFromLatLng(point.lat, point.lng))
            );
            this.polyline.visible = true;
            this.polyline.geodesic = true;
            this.polyline.width = 2;
            this.polyline.color = new Color('#8ABF5F');
            this.mapView.addPolyline(this.polyline);
        },
```

How can I convert it to the appropiate format?

Comment: That's not a valid hex code, you may directly pass the RGB color to the constructor like `new Color(1, 138, 191, 95)`.

Comment: Is it the color not being applied Or it's the wrong color being applied? Is it iOS or Android Or both? Can you show how you are creating the Polyline and when / how do you add it to map.

Answer (score 0):

You could look up the HEX conversion and then use the HEX value like this `polyline.color = new Color('#8ABF5F');`.

```
    mapView.removeAllShapes();
    // this.routeCordinates = decodePolyline(encodedPolylinePoints);
    let testPolyLine = new Polyline();        
    US_COORDINATES.map((coordinates: USCoordinate) => {
        testPolyLine.addPoint(Position.positionFromLatLng(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude));
    });
    testPolyLine.visible = true;
    testPolyLine.geodesic = true;
    testPolyLine.width = 2;
    testPolyLine.color = new Color('#8ABF5F');
    mapView.addPolyline(testPolyLine);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you seeing the wrong color or nothing at all? I accidentally pasted the polyline color I was using which is purple, try the updated answer. If that doesn't work can you post your code for the polyline and I can try it.

Comment: No color at all, are you using nativescript framework or web?

Comment: Nativescript + Angular

Comment: Edited the OP with my full method

Comment: I updated my answer with a snippet, I believe the issue is that `decodePolyline` method.